# Is this closed form correct $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\left(\cos^2\left({x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx=\gamma?$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Where $\gamma $ is Euler's constant, given that:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\left(\cos^2\left({x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx=\gamma\tag1$$

Using $$2\cos^2(A)=1+\cos(2A)$$

$(1)\implies $

$${\pi\over 4}+{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(2\cos^2\left({x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\tag2$$

$(2)\implies $

$${\pi\over 4}+{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(1+\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\tag3$$
 Using

$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$

$(3)\implies $

$${\pi\over 4}+{1\over 2}\cos(1)\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx-{1\over 2}\sin(1)\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\left(\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\tag4$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\left(\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)\right)\mathrm dx\tag5$$

Let $u=\cos\left({2x\over \pi}\right)\implies dx=-{\pi\over 2}{1\over \sin(2x/\pi)}$

$u^2=1-\sin^2(2x/\pi)$

$$I={\pi\over 2}\int_{\cos(1)}^{1}{\cos(u)\over \sqrt{1-u^2}}\mathrm du\tag6$$

Recall $$(1-x)^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(2k-1)!!\over (2k)!!}x^k$$

$(6)\implies$

$$I={\pi\over 2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(2k-1)!!\over (2k)!!}\int_{\cos(1)}^{1}u^{2k}\cos(u)\mathrm du\tag7$$

Comment: My first reaction to $(1)$ is *NAAH, that cannot be true*. But let's see...

Comment: Indeed it is not true. The difference is about $6\cdot 10^{-7}$. They are remarkably close, but not equal.

Comment: Relative Error $= 1.04 \times 10^{-4}\ \%$ !!!.